# Can I use an Arduino board as a USB encoder?

Tags: arduino, usb

Just what the title states; given an analog signal, would an Arduino board be able to both digitize, and encode the signal in a USB frame?

Comment: What sort of signal?

Comment: It's a varying voltage from a geophone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps I am not properly understanding the nuances of your question, but if you are asking if an Arduino can both digitize an analog signal (yes) and transmit it via USB to a host computer (yes) then the answer is yes to both.

If I misinterpreted what you meant by "encode the signal in a USB frame" then I apologize and please disregard this answer.

For an example with source code of a project that digitizes signals with an Arduino and displays them on a PC like an oscilloscope see http://accrochages.drone.ws/en/node/90

Comment: This answer is correct with regards to functionality.  Unless some additional requirement for type of USB encoding is added, the arduino's serial-over-USB is functionally a USB communications channel, though usually accessed via a serial-port API.

Answer (score 7):

Some, yes, some no.

The Arduino boards that use the FTDI chip can only talk on RS-232 through the USB, so no.

The Arduino boards that use the MEGA8U2 (eg the Uno), if you are willing to re-flash the U2 with a custom firmware, can communicate with whatever you want.  People have re-flashed them before so they appear to be a MIDI device.  Of course, this then stops you being able to program the Arduino as an Arduino any more.  You could get round that by linking 2 Arduinos together with the RS-232 connections and use one to program the other, or connecting some other RS-232 system to your computer to communicate with the Arduino for programming.

Of course, if you're going as far as writing custom firmware for the U2 you may as well just ditch the rest of the Arduino and just use the U2 by itself.

Comment: +1 - Sounds like a nice all bases comment. May or may not be correct as I don't know my Arduinos, but certainly SOUNDS competent :-).

Comment: Since no particular format of USB frame has been given as a requirement, encoding a sensor value in an emulated serial stream transmitted via USB packets meets the stated requirement.  The host software author has the option of obtaining the data from the operating system serial drivers, or of disabling them and obtaining it directly from the USB stack (though there would be little point in doing it that way).  The primary downside would be that the device won't identify as a custom peripheral, but as a usb serial converter or as an arduino.

Comment: Well, yes, if you want to be pedantic, that is quite correct.  However, interpreting the spirit of the question, a custom (e.g., HID) frame is implied.